# Select JavaScript array element item with jQuery selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have some json and jQuery doesn't seem to select its elements correctly. The json document I am referencing is available here: http://pastebin.com/bM3BvD2F.

the json is a array of elements and I'm trying to select one with required ID.

(you can copy-paste to http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ for a nice folded view of it)

Here's the code I have problems with:

```
    //get current picture ID - will return '2' - correct value    
    var currentID = window.location.hash ? window.location.hash.substring(1) : allImages[0]["id"];

    //this line will alert name attribute value for a picture with (id = 4) - wrong :(
   alert($(allImages[id=currentID])[0].name);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`allImages` is a plain array, so `allImages[id=currentID]` will cause temp variable called `id` to be created, assigned the value of `currentID` and return 2, causing the third element in the array to be returned. This element has indeed `id` of 4.

What you need is "deep search" and one way to do this is using the `.map` function:

```
var name = jQuery.map(allImages, function (value) {
    return (value.id == currentID) ? value : null;
})[0].name;
```

Quick test case: http://jsfiddle.net/PWPcE/

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
alert($(allImages[id=currentID]).attr('name'));
```

I think by selecting the 0th element, you are selecting the 1st character from the answer you want.

Comment: same thing - giving me name for the element with another id (4). I'm selecting [0]th element because $(allImages[id=currentID]) will return an array with one element.